# Add timestamps to H264-ES video stream gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer-1.0

I have a file with (probably, that's what `mplayer -identify` said) **H264-ES** stream.

It can be played using following `gstreamer` pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=vid.H264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

(I'm using `autovideosink` in examples, but the pipeline is much more complex - this is "minimal working example")
it plays very fast, probably as fast as my CPU allows. If I use any element that needs timestamps, it fails, because the stream has framerate `0/1`.

**I think the stream does not contain any framerate information at all.**

see:

```
$ mplayer -identify vid.H264 2>&1 | grep -i fps
FPS not specified in the header or invalid, use the -fps option.
ID_VIDEO_FPS=0.000
```

I know what the correct framerate should be (let's say it's 25fps), and I'd like to be able to **put correct timestamps into video frames** or **set correct stream framerate**.

## What I tried:

I thought that I could use `videorate` for this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=vid.H264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 \
               ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=25/1 ! autovideosink
```

but I was wrong - `videorate` tries to transform incoming stream into fixed framerate, and it sometimes looks like it works how I wanted, but when there is even slightest delay in any elements downstream, it produces "freeze-frame" video - many duplicated frames - so I thought I could use `drop-only=true` option, but it doesn't work at all:

```
$ GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=vid.H264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 \
        ! videorate drop-only=true ! video/x-raw,framerate=25/1 ! autovideosink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.030550249 31831      0x2094e10 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3470:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.044233138 31831      0x207d450 WARN                   libav gstavcodecmap.c:2408:gst_ffmpeg_caps_to_pixfmt: ignoring insane framerate 1/0
0:00:00.045314795 31831      0x207d450 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:3742:gst_pad_peer_query:<avdec_h264-0:src> could not send sticky events
0:00:00.070760684 31831      0x207d450 WARN               baseparse gstbaseparse.c:3262:gst_base_parse_loop:<h264parse0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbaseparse.c(3262): gst_base_parse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

The problem is between `avdec_h264` and `videorate` - it won't accept `framerate=0/1` caps.

What I think I need is something like (imaginary pipeline):

```
$ GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=vid.H264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 \
        ! force_timestamps framerate=25/1 ! autovideosink
```

I'm afraid I'll have to write `force_timestamps` element myself, but because I did write some elements before and it was one of the hardest and most unpleasant things I ever did, I'd much rather use existing elements, if possible.

## So my question is this:

is there some way (preferably with existing elements) to force timestamps on video frames (or gstreamer buffers) with some fixed framerate?

Answer (score 1):

Technicaly, this is not an answer because this way, the original h264 stream
is lost.

It's an ugly hack, but I needed the video and this gave me something I
could use with somewhat ok quality:

```
fn="$1"

mkdir images

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=$fn ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 \
    ! videoconvert ! jpegenc \
    ! multifilesink location=images/img%06d.jpg

gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location=images/img%06d.jpg \
    caps="image/jpeg,framerate=25/1,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1" \
    ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw \
    ! x264enc rc-lookahead=5 pass=quant quantizer=20 \
    ! avimux ! filesink location=${fn}.avi

rm -rf images
```